# ng-class does not apply when expression re-evaluates

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

*This code is from an offline network so I can't paste it here. I'm summarizing it.*

I have the following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="agent in agents" ng-class="agent.getClass()">
   <td>{{agent.server}}</td>
   <td>{{agent.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `agents` list is loaded via ajax requests.

app.js:

```
angular.module('agentsApp', [])

.controller('agentsController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    $scope.agents = {};
    $interval(function() {
       $http.get('/AgentsServlet').success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function(agent) {
                $scope.agents[agent.server] = new Agent(agent.server, agent.status);
            });
       });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Agent.js

```
var Agent = function(server, status) {
    this.server = server;
    this.status = status;
}

Agent.prototype.getClass = function() {
     return {
         success: this.status === 'RUNNING',
         error: this.status === 'ERROR'
     };
}
```

*For the record, the `AgentsServlet` load agents and their data from a simple text file.*

Now, when I change the file contents, the next ajax request will successfully load and update the table's contents BUT, the ng-class is not changed.
For example, if I change an agent's status from RUNNING to ERROR, its tr's class does not change to 'error'.

The weird thing is that if I put inside the ng-class the getClass() logic, it works, eg:

```
<tr ng-repeat="agent in agents" 
    ng-class="{success: agent.status==='RUNNING', error: agent.status==='ERROR'}">
   <td>{{agent.server}}</td>
   <td>{{agent.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

It seems that the function call is the problem and not the expression..
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: the ng-class suppose to get an array of cssClass => expression, as returned from getClass(). It should not change any field. the field status is being set in the ajax success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="agent in agents" ng-class="agent.cssClass" >
   <td>{{agent.server}}</td>
   <td>{{agent.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
function agent(server, status) {

    this.server = server;
    this.status = status;

    this.cssClass = this.status ==='RUNNING'? 'success':'error';
  }



var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.agents = [];

  var a1 = new agent(1, "RUNNING");
  var a2 = new agent(2, "ERROR");
  $scope.agents.push(a1);
  $scope.agents.push(a2);

});
```

Comment: Its not working..Its not even a correct js syntax as I know it. {} should be key => value and not only values.

Comment: This methods seems to work, but it breaks the mvc design.
I dont want to put the css class calculation inside the controller..

Comment: have you seen this http://plnkr.co/edit/DPC3rf5j3EWi2mMXdwnK?p=preview ? it is done via prototype

Answer (score 0):

Please try this : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPC3rf5j3EWi2mMXdwnK?p=preview)

function agent(server, status) {

```
    this.server = server;
    this.status = status;

    this.cssClass = this.status ==='RUNNING'? 'success':'error';
  }

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.agents = [];


  var a1 = new agent(1, "RUNNING");
  var a2 = new agent(2, "ERROR");
  $scope.agents.push(a1);
  $scope.agents.push(a2);



});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="agent in agents" ng-class="agent.cssClass" >
   <td>{{agent.server}}</td>
   <td>{{agent.status}}</td>

</tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```